# I want to get id of the class name using jquery my class name is dynamic and am getting it form url

Tags: php, jquery

This is my code

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');                          
var value = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('?') + 1);
```

I am taking id from url which is my class name 
if I get value from url value = 127
than I want to take that div id from this class name

```
<li id="li_0" onclick="changePosiotion(this.id,13767)" class="13767">
```

I want `id=li_0` for every div how can I get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the id based on the class you do

```
$('.'+value).prop('id')
```